# Show that if $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to 0} x^n = 0$ (proof confirmation)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $n \geq 3$. Derive the inequality $-x^2 \leq x^n \leq x^2$ for $-1 < x < 1$. Then, use the fact that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 = 0$ to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^n = 0$.

I suppose there are two questions here. Firstly, I did not see how to prove that $-x^2 \leq x^n \leq x^2$ for $-1 < x < 1$. This is one of those things I find to be extremely "obvious" that it ends up being difficult to see how to prove it! A hint to get started on this would be helpful!

I decided to attempt to prove the final statement without using the previous, and I did come up with something. I would like to confirm this since ignoring part of a question is usually a bad idea!

I want to show $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. whenever $|x| < \delta$, $|x^n|< \epsilon$.

Since $x \in (-1,1)$, I only need to consider $(0,1)$ since we are taking the absolute value. Write $x = \frac{1}{1 + y}$ for some $y > 0$.

Choose $\delta = min(1,(1-n)\epsilon)$. Then,

$|x^n| = |\frac{x}{(1 + y)^{n-1}}| < |\frac{\delta}{1 - n + ny}| < |\frac{\delta}{1-n}| = \epsilon$

where the middle step followed by Bernoulli's inequality. As I said, I weary having skipped an entire portion of the problem, but I am curious if this works!

Comment: The number $\delta$ is smaller than $0$, which doesn't make sense. And why do you claim that$$\left|\frac\delta{1-n+ny}\right|<\left|\frac\delta{1-n}\right|?$$

Comment: $x^2(1-x^{n-2})\ge 0$ for $n\ge 3$ and $0<x<1$. The other inequality should be similar, considering negative $x$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $ny >0$, so I was thinking that by removing it, I would make the denominator smaller? Hence making the overall fraction larger? Does it not hold because of the $-n$? Also, could I take $\delta = min(1, |1-n| \epsilon)$ to remove the worry about $\delta$ being negative?

Comment: @BenjaminWang I think I see that! If you distribute, x^2 - x^n. Then, since $x \in (0,1)$, you can argue that $x^n$ is decreasing, resulting in it being smaller than $x^2$ for $n \geq 3$. Is that essentially how it goes? If so, I can try posting an answer to it myself and seeing if I get it once I find out what's wrong with the other part!

Comment: If $\delta>0$, $n=2$ and $y=\frac14$, then$$\left|\frac\delta{1-n+ny}\right|=2\delta\quad\text{and}\quad\left|\frac\delta{1-n}\right|=\delta.$$